# Spark connect programatically to remote kerberos secured HIVE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kerberos

I am trying to connect and query HIVE tables on a remote Hadoop cluster, which is secured with kerberos. My user has necessary privileges on the cluster and i have the keytab and krb5.conf files handy. `Have already been successful connecting over JDBC, but trying to connect with this alternate approach.`

Have added the hive-site.xml, core-site.xml etc. files in the classpath of the Intellij.

Here is what i have tried till now.

```
package org.nexus.spark.kerberos

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{JdbcDialect, JdbcDialects}

object SparkHiveConnect {
  val logger: Logger = Logger("SparkHiveConnect")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "jaas.conf")
    System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug", "true")
    System.setProperty("java.security.debug", "gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext")
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false")
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf")
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "true")
    System.setProperty("hive.security.authorization.enabled", "false")
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", "hive/_PRINCIPAL")
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", "true")
    System.setProperty("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "HADOOP_HOME")
    System.setProperty("spark.home", "SPARK_HOME")

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("Scala Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hostname:9083")
      .config("spark.yarn.keytab", "my-keytab")
      .config("spark.yarn.principal", "user@PRINCIPAL")
      .config("spark.hadoop.spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/warehouse")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate();

    spark.sql("select * from testtable").show()
  }
}
```

`jaas.conf` file is as follows

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=false
  doNotPrompt=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="file:/my-ketab"
  principal="user@PRINCIPAL"
  debug=true;
};
```

The above code starts to execute and even successfully connects to metastore, but gets stuck afterwards

```
19:12:34.103 [main] INFO  o.s.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7a24eb3{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19:12:34.104 [main] INFO  o.s.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4fe875be{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19:12:34.804 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils - Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
19:12:34.825 [main] INFO  o.a.s.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl - Attempting to login to Kerberos using principal: user@PRINCIPAL and keytab: my-keytab.keytab
19:12:35.255 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://hostname:9083
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is my-keytab.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is user@PRINCIPAL tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is user@PRINCIPAL
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded 

19:12:38.672 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
```

Upon running in debug mode, i see the following details printing in infinite loop

```
19:15:05.278 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
19:15:07.244 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - CLIENT: reading data length: 34
19:15:07.244 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - writing data length: 42
19:15:07.536 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - CLIENT: reading data length: 34
19:15:07.536 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - writing data length: 48
19:15:07.827 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - CLIENT: reading data length: 34
19:15:07.827 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - writing data length: 48
19:15:08.178 [main] DEBUG o.a.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - CLIENT: reading data length: 34
```

Any suggestions on what i might be doing wrong are much appreciated.

Comment: By any chance did you get this working?

Comment: Wasn't able to figure out this issue @GouthamAnush

Comment: I guess this has something to do with the HDFS config files core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml, hive-site.xml, etc. I am trying to get this working. I will let you know if I make it through.